# how can I make a function which will return a number of Schedule Dates that are matching with other Item_date from my database

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I want to create a function where Item_date will be received from my Database and will return a **number of Schedule Dates that are matching with other Item_date**.

For instance, I can select 2021-05-20, and the function will return :

19th November: 2 Scheduled

18th November: 2 Scheduled

Can anyone give me an idea of how can I make it?

This is my database example:

```
[
    {
        "schedule_time": "2021-05-17 12:39:29",
        "slot": "L",
        "item_date": "2021-05-18"
    },
    {
        "schedule_time": "2021-05-17 12:47:53",
        "slot": "D",
        "item_date": "2021-05-18"
    },
    {
        "schedule_time": "2021-05-18 13:55:22",
        "slot": "D",
        "item_date": "2021-05-19"
    },
    {
        "schedule_time": "2021-05-19 16:09:15",
        "slot": "L",
        "item_date": "2021-05-20"
    },
    {
        "schedule_time": "2021-05-19 16:11:55",
        "slot": "L",
        "item_date": "2021-05-20"
    },...

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the other dates you need to do this
suppose array is the array where your database info are ,
and the dbItemDate the parameter passed to javascript :

```
let dbItemDate="2021-05-20";
let otherDayArray= array.filter(num=>num.item_date!=dbItemDate);
console.log(otherDayArray);//this is the new array of others date 
let count = otherDayArray.reduce(function(acc,num){
    
    acc[num.item_date]=(acc[num.item_date]||0)+1;
    return acc;
},[]);
console.log(count);//this should print the frequency of each date in the others date array
```

and if you want the same date just replace the condition in array.filter to

```
let otherDayArray= array.filter(num=>num.item_date===dbItemDate);
```